# Error running selenium grid chrome webdriver on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, selenium

I set up selenium grid and node on amazon ec2.I am able to see grid and node configuration in the browser

i downloaded latest chromewebdriver - 2.16 and put under usr/bin on my amazon ec2 linux machine.

When i am trying to run a selenium test against chrome browser it is throwing me the below error

./chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: 
 libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I am stuck here for 2 days.Please help

Comment: Please elaborate on what you've tried, so we know what didn't work. From what I can tell, though, gconf 2 is a missing dependency for what you're doing, did you try installing it? I'd start with `sudo yum search "gconf"`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a library. Did you check all the dependencies? `gconf2` is what you're looking for. I don't have an EC2 instance handy to see which package specifically you need, but it's definitely `gconf2`.